# How does the Turkish government have an audio recording of Jamal Khashoggi's killing?

Tags: assassinations

The Turkish government has an audio recording of Jamal Khashoggi's killing in the Saudi Consulate in Istanbul.

How did the Turkish government obtain this recording? Do they have the consulate bugged? If they do, is that a breach of international law concerning consulates or an agreement between the two countries?

Comment: Nobody can know that for sure unless the Turkish government tells us (which it so far hasn’t done).

Comment: There was some talk about the audio having been captured by Khashoggi's smartwatch that would have sent it to Kashoggi's iPhone (who his fiancé had on her while waiting nearby), but later some experts did reject this theory (the Apple smartwatchs available in Turkey did not have this function, and the fiance would have been too far away for it to work, among other reasons).

Comment: Most probable explanation? Turkey has microphones in every embassy they have been able to put them - and where they have failed to remove them. Embassies are well known secret service offices - some states use them in that way more than others, and obviously they do it more in certain countries of interest, but every country does that. So they are an obvious target for counter-intelligence services.

Comment: @SJuan76 _"the Apple smartwatchs available in Turkey did not have this function"_ considering how widely traveled he was I'm not sure you can really attribute any relevance to that, unless of course it's on record that the items in question were purchased in Turkey.